Elastic.Serilog.Sinks and Failed publish over channel: EcsDataStreamChannel`1
I'm trying to use ElasticSearch in place of Logz.Io.. I've my ElasticSearch instance running on Azure and I'm trying to run this integration test.
[Fact]
public void WriteLog_WritesMessageToSerilog()
{
    // Arrange

    var nodes = new[] { new Uri("https://OMISS.kb.eastus.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243") };
    
    var message = "Test message";
    // We'll use a StringWriter to capture the output of the logger
    
    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()

        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(nodes, opts =>
        {
            
            opts.AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv7;
            
            opts.ChannelDiagnosticsCallback = diagnosticCallBack;
            opts.BootstrapMethod = BootstrapMethod.Failure;
            opts.DataStream = new DataStreamName("logs", "console-example") ; 
            opts.ConfigureChannel = channelOpts =>
            {
                channelOpts.BufferOptions = new BufferOptions { ExportMaxConcurrency = 10 };
            };
        }, transport =>
        {
            
        })

        .CreateLogger();
    // Act
    logger.Information(message);
    // Assert
     
}

When I run it I got the following error in the callback:
Failed publish over channel: EcsDataStreamChannel`1.
Exported Buffers: 0
Exported Items: 0
Export Responses: 0
Export Retries: 0
Export Exhausts: 0
Export Returned Items to retry: False
Inbound Buffer Read Loop Started: False
Inbound Buffer Publishes: 0
Inbound Buffer Publish Failures: 0
Outbound Buffer Read Loop Started: False
Outbound Buffer Read Loop Exited: False
Outbound Buffer Publishes: 0
Outbound Buffer Publish Failures: 0
Exception: None


I'm using the official ElasticSearch search Serilog nuget Elastic.Serilog.Sinks 8.11.1
Any suggestion to start looking at this error?
